# Pegar valor de Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sei que o título faz parecer que já tenha milhões desta pergunta, mas vamos lá.

O meu caso funciona assim, eu tenho um DataList para que possa autocompletar buscando em um array de objetos. Quando eu pego esse array, ele vai me retornar um dos itens e este item eu vou procurar pelo html dele, html que está com o mesmo nome que o item.

A questão é, como eu pego somente um dos valores? O valor que está escrito no Input??

```js
jsonOptions = [
    {"product": "22222", "description": "description 2"}, 
    {"product": "33333", "description": "description 3"}, 
    {"product": "44444", "description": "description 4"}, 
    {"product": "55555", "description": "description 5"}, 
    {"product": "66666", "description": "description 6"},
    {"product": "77777", "description": "description 7"}
    
     ]; 
          
$(document).ready(function() {
        
   var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');         
 
         
          
 jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
  
  var option = document.createElement('option');
      
  option.value = item.description;
  option.text = item.product;
  option.setAttribute('data-product', item.product);
  dataList.appendChild(option);
    });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="json-datalist" placeholder="Nome ou Número">
<datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
```

Olhem o código, é bem simples.. O que quero fazer é pegar o valor de descrição e usar ele como parâmetro para buscar por uma página html.. Também preciso daquele production que procurar pelo número também será uma opção.

Comment: Considere alterar o título para que ele seja mais específico ao problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione o evento `input` ao campo.

```
var inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var value = this.value;
  var opt = [].find.call(this.list.options, function(option) {
    return option.value === value;
  });
  if(opt) {
    alert('Product: ' + opt.textContent + '\nDescription: ' + opt.value);
  }
});
```

#### Veja funcionando

```js
jsonOptions = [
  {"product": "22222", "description": "description 2"}, 
  {"product": "33333", "description": "description 3"}, 
  {"product": "44444", "description": "description 4"}, 
  {"product": "55555", "description": "description 5"}, 
  {"product": "66666", "description": "description 6"},
  {"product": "77777", "description": "description 7"}

]; 

$(document).ready(function() {
        
  var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');         

  jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

    var option = document.createElement('option');

    option.value = item.description;
    option.text = item.product;
    option.setAttribute('data-product', item.product);
    dataList.appendChild(option);
  });
  
  var inp = document.querySelector('input');
  inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    var opt = [].find.call(this.list.options, function(option) {
      return option.value === value;
    });
    if(opt) {
      alert('Product: ' + opt.textContent + '\nDescription: ' + opt.value)
    }
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="json-datalist" placeholder="Nome ou Número">
<datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
```

#### Referências

- [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input)

Comment: Parabéns por sua resposta amigo, resolveu 100%. Muito obrigado.